# Responsive image grid gallery for vue js

Tags: vue.js, grid, vuejs2, vue-component, photo-gallery

I need a responsive image grid component for vue that show images with different size . There are some good [jquery plugins](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/06/gamma-gallery-a-responsive-image-gallery-experiment/) for that , but I cannot use it in my vue based page because of lazy load of images in scroll. the jquery set heights and widths only in the initial page load . Is there any good component or a solution to use the jquery plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great component for it : [vue-masonry](https://github.com/shershen08/vue-masonry)

Answer (score 3):

I created a lightweight package that allows you to do this without having to know the image sizes beforehand: [vue-stack-grid](https://github.com/WouterFlorijn/vue-stack-grid).